# Check if a https webpage exists in python

Tags: python, http

In a python 2.x script, I am looking for functionality to check if a https page returns particular content (will likely need to parse the page content to discover this). The page has a htpasswd prompt as well, which needs to be auth'd with a username and password to be able to see the content. So I suppose I am looking for a module or other functionality that provides the ability for me to hardcode a username and password so it can fetch the page and I can manipulate the output (aka check if the equivalent of keywords representing a 404 page are present).

I was having a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html but it doesn't seem to do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do it with the `httplib` module but there are easier methods that don't require manual driving of the HTTP protocol.

Using the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) (an external module requiring installation first) is probably simplest:

```
import requests

auth = ('someusername', 'somepassword')
response = requests.get(yoururl, auth=auth)
response.raise_for_status()
```

This will raise an exception if the response wasn't successful or returned a 404 Not Found.

You can then further parse the response body with `response.content` (byte string) or `response.text` (a unicode response).

Using *just* the standard library, using the [`urllib2` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) would look like:

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request(yoururl)
authstring = base64.encodestring('{}:{}'.format('someusername', 'somepassword')).strip()
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic {}".format(authstring))   
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

if not 200 <= response.getcode() < 400:
    # error response, raise an exception here?

content = response.read()
try:
    text = content.decode(response.info().getparam('charset', 'utf8'))
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    text = content.decode('ascii', 'replace')
```

where `content` is the byte string contents of the response body, and `text` would be the unicode value, up to a point.